# HighCharts tooltip while dragging

Tags: charts, highcharts, tooltip, drag

I am trying to implement drag and drop functionality in highcharts. But I am facing 2 problems:

1. Secondary Y-Axis is not seems to be working, any reason why the line of for Phasing series is showing like this?
2. How can I show the sum of Phasing series in tooltip while user is dragging, how can I do it in drag event?

Basically only the uplift series is draggable and the sum of all points in that series should be exactly 100.

Comment: see my sample http://jsfiddle.net/ZQQpS/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since all points have the same calue, Highcharts can't calculate yAxis - set min or max for second yAxis, to give some more information for calculations: http://jsfiddle.net/ZQQpS/9/
2. Why you want to do it in drag event? Use `tooltip.formatter` - there loop through all points using `this.point.series.data` and sum values to display in a tooltip.

Comment: Thanks for this, I managed to fix Y-Axis issue. Regarding tooltip, will it take the new Y-Axis value to calculate sum while I'm dragging?

Comment: One more thing http://jsfiddle.net/ZQQpS/13/. How can I update the legend totals in on drop event?